How to animate/transition from top down in next js on a responsive mobile menu?
How can i add a topdown slide in transition in next js using tailwind?
I've tried having two different classes and using the translate/top properties but none seem to be working.
i've looked up on several places on youtube and google but cant seem to find any. Chatgpt doesn't seem to know a thing about this either.


import { NAV_LINKS } from "@/constants";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";



const MobileMenu = () => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const menuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        if (menuRef.current && !(menuRef.current as Node).contains(event.target as Node)) {
            setActive(false);
        }
    };

      document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);

      return () => {
          document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
      };
    }, []);


    const handleToggle = () => {
      setActive(prevActive => !prevActive);
    };
  

    
 

  return (
    <div className='lg:hidden' ref={menuRef}>
        {/* Hamburger Icon */}
        <div className="cursor-pointer">
            <Image
              src='/burger-menu.svg'
              alt='hamburger menu icon'
              width={34}
              height={34}
              onClick={handleToggle}
              className={active ? 'animateBurger' : ''}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <ul className={active ? 'animateMobileMenu' : 'mobileMenu'}>
            {NAV_LINKS.map((link) => (
              <Link href={link.href} key={link.key}>
                {link.label}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
 
    </div>
  )
}

export default MobileMenu



Here is the CSS code as well.


  .animateBurger{
    @apply transition rotate-90 opacity-25
  }

  .animateMobileMenu{
    @apply transition-all p-24 flex justify-center items-center flex-col z-50 fixed 
    top-20 left-0 w-full gap-12 text-white-10 regular-16 border border-gray-800 
    bg-black-100/75 backdrop-blur-sm
  }

  .mobileMenu{
    @apply lg:hidden hidden
  }



